# Advantages of self.attribute vs. @attribute?

Tags: ruby

Assuming the following:

```
def create_new_salt
  self.salt = self.object_id.to_s + rand.to_s
end
```

Why is it better to use the 'self.' rather than an instance variable '@salt'?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `self.salt =` will cause the `salt=` method to be used, if defined. This is useful for ensuring any error checking / transformations inside the `salt=` method are used. However, it means there must be an explicit `salt=` method (possibly created by `attr_accessor`, for example), and this isn't necessarily a good idea.

Summary: use `self.salt =` if you have a custom `salt=` method; use `@salt =` if you know exactly what you want `@salt` to be, or if you don't have a custom `salt=` method.

Final note: I'd probably write it like this (in my opinion it's a little clearer)

```
def create_new_salt
  @salt = "#{object_id}#{rand}"
end
```

EDIT: thanks to @Chuck's comments on another answer, I've modified this to remove the `self.`-free code - it was wrong.

Comment: Thanks so much Peter!  I agree, I like your version better.

Answer (score 4):

Besides Peter's great answer, I usually signal in Ruby that I'm using `attr_accessor` by using self.attr= and self.attr instead of @attr.

Edit: Without "self.", you're creating a local variable. Yikes.

Comment: In fact, just writing `salt = 5` without specifying `self` as the receiver *will* create a local variable.

Comment: @Chuck, this is a very important point which I didn't realise. I've modified my answer.

Comment: wow, been programming ruby forever and somehow never knew this, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Further to Peter's answer:

Another interesting point is that `self.salt=` can be invoked even if the salt= method is private. This is an exception to the normal Ruby rule that a private method can not be invoked with an explicit receiver.